# how to degrade with pushstate? backbone.history or history.js?

Tags: html, backbone.js, pushstate, history.js

I'd like to use pushstate (make a ajax request, change url, and adjust browser history stack)

Since pushstate is not supported in every browser, I'll have to do something about that.

Backbone seems to offer such a capability but failed to find a good documentation how I should use it for the purpose. (I'm already using backbone/backbone-relational and so on, but completely clueless on backbone's router or history related stuff)

Or history.js seems to offer such capability too.

How do I use either of them?

Answer (score 0):

```
Backbone.history.start()
```

this will let Backbone to start monitoring `hashchange` events